# can't figure out HTML cURL to JavaScript json of body part in RestAPI

Tags: javascript, rest, api, http, curl

I'm trying to use the moneybird api ([documentation](https://developer.moneybird.com/api/documents_receipts/)) to upload a receipt to my account using the XHR posting method.
I've got the connection working fine, but I can't seem to figure out (after a lot of googling and looking at practical examples) how to parse the cURL data part of the post to a JavaScript compatible one (json if i'm correct?).

This is the example moneybird gives in their documentation:

`curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 84ec207ad0154a508f798e615a998ac1fd752926d00f955fb1df3e144cba44ab" \
  -XPATCH \
  -d '{"receipt":{"details_attributes":{"0":{"id":226902553790514831,"description":"updated description","price":20}}}}' \
  https://moneybird.com/api/v2/123/documents/receipts/226902553785271950.json`

And it's this part that that I need to somehow parse/convert:`'{"receipt":{"details_attributes":{"0":{"id":226902553790514831,"description":"updated description","price":20}}}}' \`

To fit in with my JavaScript code:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', 'https://moneybird.com/api/v2/myId/documents/receipts');

request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer myApiKey');
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log('Status:', this.status);
        console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
        console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
    }
};

var body = "cURL/converted json has to be in this place"


request.send(body);
```

If it will help you, there is a ruby example in the documentation as well, but as I'm not familiar with this language it didn't help me much.

Altough this is running on a website I prefer this to be in JavaScript, but if you have another/better solution, I'm happy to try it.

Comment: `var body = JSON.stringify(some_object);` where `some_object` is your receipt object. Just curious, do you need to be using xhr2 for any particular reason? How about using something like axios which will handle your request quite a bit more legibly?

Comment: I was gonna say use `fetch` or `request`. @CharlieSchliesser recommendation of `axios` is great as well. Looking at this is painful :) Also, the response data you need to handle needs to be handled in `request.onreadystatechange` because the request is asynchronous.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin this is done in the function, or am i wrong?

Comment: @tjallo no, looks like you are good. Just wanted to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cURL data structure you have provided in your example looks like this when formatted as JSON:

```
{  
   "receipt":{  
      "details_attributes":{  
         "0":{  
            "id":226902553790514831,
            "description":"updated description",
            "price":20
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I asume you need to populate id, description and price with the correct values you are wanting to post. If you need to post multiple line items you would add additional entries in the "details_attributes" object. Like below:

```
{  
   "receipt":{  
      "details_attributes":{  
         "0":{  
            "id":226902553790514831,
            "description":"updated description",
            "price":20
         },
         "1":{  
            "id": "Another ID",
            "description":"Another Description",
            "price": "Another Price"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Once you have your payload defined in the body variable, you will need to convert it to JSON string and post it using XHR.send(), like this:

```
request.send(JSON.stringify(body));
```

I would also recommend looking into something like '[fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)' or '[axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)' to simplify the request process.

Finally reading the documentation quickly you also need to change you API endpoint for moneybird to include '.json'

```
var myId = 123; 
request.open('POST', `https://moneybird.com/api/v2/${myId}/documents/receipts.json`);
```

Comment: Using this i get the following error: 
Body: {"error":"token is invalid","symbolic":{"request":"invalid_grant"}}

Comment: i've fixed the question above by myself sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: if I was able to gel @tjallo are you able to make my answer as correct.